# Environment.UserName returning application pool name instead of username

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, user-identification

The following line

```
Environment.UserName
```

In debug mode in visual studio returns the identity of the user like I need.

Then when I set up my site in IIS and run the code the same line returns the name of the application pool which the site uses.

How can I get it to still return the user name ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   string username = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Important note: You need to configure IIS to enable integrated security and disable anonymous logon.

Note that `Environment.Username` returns the Username on the current Thread.

Comment: So there is no login to this application at the moment, it's just something for local users on the network. I just wanted to be able to capture user identities

Comment: This should work with Windows authentication. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok so right now it's not getting into the if loop because basically there is no Authentication set up. How do I set up Windows Authentication on the app ?

Comment: configure IIS to enable integrated security

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]
```

It will return `DOMAIN\USERNAME`. You can then split it etc.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.
Use  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME") for current Login username.

Link :https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/the-environment-class-in-C-Sharp/

Comment: Environment.UserName, returns name if the user who started the current thread but Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERNAME") returns you login user name.

Comment: Done lot of research and finally this worked with me.

Answer (score 1):

In IIS, for your application, please .
**Enable ASP.NET Impersonation**
[image]