# Environment.UserName returning as SYSTEM rather than User's name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been using

```
Environment.UserName
```

To display the current user's name and it's been working all this time.

However, started working on my project today - `Environment.UserName` has returned the word `"SYSTEM"` despite the user name still being the same as it was before.

Comment: Hello! Does this answer your question?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111687/environment-username-returning-application-pool-name-instead-of-username

Comment: [`Environment.UserName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.environment.username) `The user name of the person who is logged on to the operating system.` or what describes it actually better: `You can use the UserName property to identify the user on the current thread` ... is it possible your app / UnityEditor is running as the Windows administrator user called "System"?

Comment: are you using windows service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Happened to us too 3 days ago, we were reaching the documents and settings via `Environment.UserName` (i guess it was a windows update)

We solved it by using %USERPROFILE% instead of `Environment.UserName` in the string.

```
 readonly string savedFilesDirectoryPath =
     Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%USERPROFILE%\Documents\OurProjectName");
```

%USERPROFILE% env var on windows indicates where a user home directory is located in the file system

For your exact question tho: I think in build mode your solution will work actually so try that